# Is it possible to stop the active selector from being removed on resize?

Tags: css, sass

I have a form where the labels' css changes if the label is active. The label becomes active when the user starts typing in the input.

If there is text in the input and the user resizes their screen the active label is removed. Is there a way to make sure the active label does not get removed on resize?

```
label {
  color: $blue;
  &.active {
    color: $green;
    background-color: rgba($red, 0.7);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not showing us Javascript that toggles the `active` class.

Comment: When you resize, the tag it is no longer active, so it stops displaying the color green. When doing resize it is the window that is active.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: You're certainly using a css framework. Tell use which framework, and the best is to provide a minimal exemple as it said... with a fiddle or the builting code fiddle...